# A kind of Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Given a $z\in \mathbb{C}^N$, the DFT of $z$ is given for every $k\in [0,N-1]_\mathbb{N}$ by
$$DFT_z(k)=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} z_j\, \omega^{-k j}$$ where I have denoted by $\omega$ the $N$-th root of unit. That discrete transform is weel known and studied.

I was wondering if it is also well known and studied the following generalization $$GDFT_z(k)=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} z_{kj}\, \omega^{-k j},$$ in which $z$ is now an $N\times N$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$.

[Question] Is it still possible to compute my GDFT  in $O(N \log N)$?

Thanks in advance,
Josh

Comment: Since your transform converts a matrix into a vector, it's not invertible.  Invertibility is a key property of Fourier Transform in any context.

Comment: You are right but this is irrilevant for what I need. The question is if someone of you have ever seen a sistematic study of that sum. Best, Josh.

Comment: Your general DFT is just the restriction of an $N$-tuple of DFTs along the diagonal.  That is, you really have a more general DFT:
$$MGDFT_z(\ell,k)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}z_{\ell,j} \omega^{-kj}$$
which is invertible, but you are forgetting most of the information by setting $k=\ell$.  MGDFTs appear in many places, since they are just vector-valued DFTs.  I have never seen an application of the GDFT by itself - you can certainly prove elementary properties like norm bounds by passing to the MGDFT, but if you don't tell us what sort of specific results you seek it is difficult to say more.

Comment: Hi Carnahan, thank you very much for the answer. Can you give me some reference for that? In particular my interest is in discovering if there exists a kind of FFT for what I call the GDFT (an $O(N \log N)$ algorithm). Thanks in advance

Comment: Once I studied the variant of modified DFT with permutations of original rows or columns. In this case most properties are the same as for classical DFT (unitarian, explicit inversion). An interest was in spectral properties, they are different, this transform is known and useful in codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no $O(N \log N)$ algorithm, because your computer will take $N^2$ computations to even read the entries of the matrix $z$.  However, you definitely get $O(N^2 \log N)$ since this is the usual DFT done $N$ times and suitably restricted.